# Edit DataGridView during Runtime and Update Database

Tags: vb.net

I am working on VB.Net. In my windows form i have a datagridview control and modify button. I want to modify the cell/row from datagridview in sql server 2008. plz suggest me simple code for this.

Comment: after modify click button the data should be modify in database. without textboxes

Comment: Check this Link Its Will help you [1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993558/how-to-update-database-by-using-datagridview-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

On CellClick event of Datagridview you can fetch the value identifying the record uniquely (primary key). Here is the code sample

```
    Id = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value ' Here 0 is the cell index having primary key
```

Then on button click event you can fire the query of Update or Delete passing id as argument. After that you can load the datagridview again.